# Extract leaf nodes of multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array in PHP that looks like this

```
array
(
   array(0)
   (
       array(0)
       (
         .
         . 
         .
       )

       .
       .
       array(10)
       (
         ..
       )
   )

   .
   . 
   .
   array(n)
   (

     array(0)
     (
     )
   )
 )
```

And I need all the leaf elements of this mulit-dimensional array into a linear array, how should I go about doing this without resorting recursion, such like this?

```
 function getChild($element)
 {

     foreach($element as $e)
     {

       if (is_array($e)
       {
          getChild($e);
       }
     }
 }
```

Note: code snippet above, horribly incompleted

Update: example of array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Seller Object
                        (
                            [credits:private] => 5000000
                            [balance:private] => 4998970
                            [queueid:private] => 0
                            [sellerid:private] => 2
                            [dateTime:private] => 2009-07-25 17:53:10
                        )

                )

        )
```

...snipped.

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Seller Object
                    (
                        [credits:private] => 10000000
                        [balance:private] => 9997940
                        [queueid:private] => 135
                        [sellerid:private] => 234
                        [dateTime:private] => 2009-07-14 23:36:00
                    )

            )

    ....snipped....

    )
```

)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use recursion? Seems like the most appropriate technique.

Comment: what exactly is horribly incomplete about this this snippet?

Comment: I've leave out the final array to collect the elements, and left out the else part of the if statement; 

As for why no recursion, it's just a personal preference, and a fear of the script going into an infinite loop.

Comment: your fear is irrational.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, there is a single function that will do the trick, check the manual page at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Quick snippet adapted from the page:

```
$data = array('test' => array('deeper' => array('last' => 'foo'), 'bar'), 'baz');

var_dump($data);

function printValue($value, $key, $userData) 
{
    //echo "$value\n";
    $userData[] = $value;
}


$result = new ArrayObject();
array_walk_recursive($data, 'printValue', $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use iterators, for example:

```
$result = array();
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY) as $value) {
    $result[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to confirm with you if this works? I tried it but the loop never executes

Comment: I tested it with a simple array, and it does work, maybe you could post an example of the array you are using. I tried `$array = array(
 array('a', array( 'b','c','d', array('f'))), 'c' );`

Comment: Appreciate the help, I have updated my question with a live example. Does it matter that the leaf nodes are classes?

Comment: ah, i think the iterator will iterate through objects as if they are an array, so this probably won't work, sorry

Comment: @VolkerK I agree with you that we should use more SPL but your comment is nearly 6 years old and still there's close to zero documentation for the SPL methods on php.net except for their interface. I really think that this is one of the reasons it's still so rarely used.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function getLeafs($element) {
    $leafs = array();
    foreach ($element as $e) {
        if (is_array($e)) {
            $leafs = array_merge($leafs, getLeafs($e));
        } else {
            $leafs[] = $e;
        }
    }
    return $leafs;
}
```

---

**Edit**   Apparently you don’t want a recursive solution. So here’s an iterative solution that uses a stack:

```
function getLeafs($element) {
    $stack = array($element);
    $leafs = array();
    while ($item = array_pop($stack)) {
        while ($e = array_shift($item)) {
            if (is_array($e)) {
                array_push($stack, array($item));
                array_push($stack, $e);
                break;
            } else {
                $leafs[] = $e;
            }
        }
    }
    return $leafs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a stack:

```
<?php

$data = array(array(array("foo"),"bar"),"baz");

$results = array();
$process = $data;
while (count($process) > 0) {
    $current = array_pop($process);
    if (is_array($current)) {
        // Using a loop for clarity. You could use array_merge() here.
        foreach ($current as $item) {
            // As an optimization you could add "flat" items directly to the results array here.
            array_push($process, $item);
        }
    } else {
        array_push($results, $current);
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => baz
    [1] => bar
    [2] => foo
)
```

This should be more memory efficient than the recursive approach. Despite the fact that we do a lot of array manipulation here, PHP has copy-on-write semantics so the actual zvals of the real data won't be duplicated in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Just got the same issue and used another method that was not mentioned. The accepted answer require the [`ArrayObject` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) to work properly. It can be done with the `array` primitive and the `use` keyword in the [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (PHP >= 5.3):

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array(1,2,3,4,5),
    array(6,7,8,9,0),
);
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($data, function($v) use (&$result) { # by reference
    $result[] = $v;
});
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no flatten function to get directly the leafs. You have to use recursion to check for each array if has more array children and only when you get to the bottom to move the element to a result flat array.