# How to merge array with same key into single array with all the key

Tags: php

I want to merge array with the same name and show all the same name in a single array.

I have array show below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location_name] => NTPL Vault
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [location_name] => NTPL Safe Room
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [location_name] => Safe NTPL
        )

)




$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $myArray);
```

I am expecting output as below...

```
[
  {
    "location_name": "NTPL"
  },
  {
    "location_name": "NJKL"
  },
  {
    "location_name": "KLDF"
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove first levels of identifier in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481980/remove-first-levels-of-identifier-in-array)

Comment: these two things you written are the same

Comment: Or maybe you need `json_encode`.

Comment: @Zeljka actually not, look at the values. But how those values got transformed is anyone's guess

Comment: you are right @Andreas i didnt saw that values are different

Comment: Your two examples are same kind of array but noted differently.
One is the output of php's `var_dump` and one is in json.
You need to explain more what you really want (to do).

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is in JSON format, for which there are two commonly used functions in PHP:

- [json_encode();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)
- [json_decode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270016/json-decode-in-php);

For changing arrays from PHP forms to JSON, you might use `json_encode` and vice versa:

```
$array = array
    (
    '0' => array
    (
        'location_name' => 'NTPL Vault',
    ),

    '1' => array
    (
        'location_name' => 'NTPL Safe Room',
    ),

    '2' => array
    (
        'location_name' => 'Safe NTPL',
    ),

);

$output = json_encode($array);
var_dump($output);
```

#### Output:

```
string(97) "[{"location_name":"NTPL Vault"},{"location_name":"NTPL Safe Room"},{"location_name":"Safe NTPL"}]"
```

If you wish to change the values of `location_name`, you might simply use other functions.