# Get lowermost level of php array

Tags: php, prestashop

I have this array from prestashop:

```
[11]=>
[id_category] => 11
[children] => 
    [12]=>
        [id_category] => 12
        [children] =>
            [13]=>
                [id_category] => 14
```

I want get last level of this array that is the 13 array. For get this array I use Category::getNestedCategories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract leaf nodes of multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181691/extract-leaf-nodes-of-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Although the link above may give you extra nodes, it may be a useful starting point.

Comment: if you've got array like this - the solution could be the same regardless of the engine you use. BUT!!! what do you want to get if you have two or more child branches on some level??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$tree = [
    'id_category' => 11,
    'children' => [
        12 => [
            'id_category' => 12,
            'children' => [
                13 => [
                    'id_category' => 13,
                    'children' => [
                        14 => [
                            'id_category' => 14
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                15 => [
                    'id_category' => 15
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

function findMaxDepth(array $data): int
{
    $maxDepth = 0;
    if (isset($data['children'])) {
        // if there'are children of the node collect maxs on this level
        foreach ($data['children'] as $child) {
            // go on next level
            $depth = findMaxDepth($child);
            if ($maxDepth < $depth) {
                $maxDepth = $depth;
            }
        }
    }
    return $maxDepth + 1;
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
$max = findMaxDepth($tree);
```

Result will be 4

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function:-

```
function findLowestChild($arr, $level = 0, $lowestArr = ['level'=>0, 'value'=> null]){

    if(isset($arr['children']) && is_array($arr['children'])) {
        $level++;
        foreach($arr['children'] as $childArr) {
            $lowestArr = findLowestChild($childArr, $level, $lowestArr);
        }
    } else {
        if($lowestArr['level'] < $level) {
            $lowestArr['level'] = $level;
            $lowestArr['value'] = $arr;
        }
    }
    return $lowestArr;
}
```

Call it like findLowestChild($yourArray);
It will give you level value as well as the lowest value array.